# writing to second column of a csv file python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a Python program that gets the google rating for restaurants after reading the names of the restaurants from a CSV file (has only a single column). The names are in a single column (first one). it gets the rating for each restaurant and appends it to a list. Now i need to make a second column and pass that list into the second column. Here is my CSV file (it doesn't have headers, i.e names of columns)

```
Barrafina london
palomar london
fateema london
five guys london
10 greek street london
edition hotel london
```

And here is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main():
    global rate
    ratings = []
    res = []
    with open('CSV restaurants example.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for row1 in reader:
            for row in row1:
                res.append(row)
    for restaurant in res:
        try:
            re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + restaurant)
        except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
            re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + restaurant)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, 'html.parser')

        rating = soup.select_one('.oqSTJd')
        try:
            rate = rating.text
            ratings.append(rate)
        except AttributeError:
            print("google search is asking for captcha, use a proxy or change your wifi network")
            exit()

        print('\nThe rating for ' + restaurant + ' is ' + str(rate) + ' out of 5 ' + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Any suggestions on how can i append that list to second column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a `csv.writer` to compliment your `csv.reader`.  You want to save the output as a new file, I recommend *never* overwriting your raw data, even if you are just adding data to it.

I will say that you probably want to be careful about the delimiter, as the location and restaurant fields seem to be merged, that looks like two columns in an ill-formed csv to me.

Here you can solve it in the same for-loop:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main():
    # global rate
    # ratings = []
    # res = []
    with open('CSV restaurants example.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as infd, \
             open('restaurants_with_ratings.csv') as outfd:
        reader = csv.reader(infd)

        # create a csv writer, these are defaults, but I'm showing that 
        # you can choose formatting
        writer = csv.writer(outfd, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

        # if there's only one column, the comma works here.
        for restaurant, in reader:
            # res.append(row)

            try:
                re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + restaurant)
            except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
                re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + restaurant)

            soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, 'html.parser')

            rating = soup.select_one('.oqSTJd')
            try:
                rate = rating.text
                writer.writerow([restauant, rate])  # add a column
                # ratings.append(rate)
            except AttributeError:
                print("google search is asking for captcha, use a proxy or change your wifi network")
                exit()

            print('\nThe rating for ' + restaurant + ' is ' + str(rate) + ' out of 5 ' + '\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it creates a pandas object with a second column of ratings and you can convert it to csv:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv


def main():
    global rate
    ratings = []
    res = []
    with open('CSV restaurants example.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)

        for row1 in reader:
            for row in row1:
                res.append(row)
    for restaurant in res:
        try:
            re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + restaurant)
        except requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError:
            re = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=' + restaurant)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(re.content, 'html.parser')

        rating = soup.select_one('.oqSTJd')
        try:
            rate = rating.text
            ratings.append(rate)
        except AttributeError:
            print("google search is asking for captcha, use a proxy or change your wifi network")
            exit()

        print('\nThe rating for ' + restaurant + ' is ' + str(rate) + ' out of 5 ' + '\n')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('CSV restaurants example.csv', header=None, names=['Restaurants']) 
    df2['ratings'] = ratings
    print(df2)
    print("")
    print(df2.to_csv())
    return df2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    df2 = main()
```

You can rewrite back to csv without headers like this:

```
df2.set_index("Restaurants").to_csv(header=False)

# 'Barrafina london,4.5\npalomar london,4.6\nfateema london,4.8\nfive guys london,4.2\n10 greek street london,4.5\nedition hotel london,4.6\n'
```